# Do I need a graphics card driver for Linux?

Tags: 12.04, graphics, kde, playonlinux

I am using Linux with a KDE desktop environment and the following hardware configuration:

• Intel Core i7 3.4GHhz 4770k
• MSI Z87 MPower motherboard
• MSI GeForce GTX760 2GB DDR5 graphics card
• 1TB hard drive
• 16GB RAM

Do I need to install a graphics card driver?

Comment: I cann't find "Additional Driers" in KDE

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete guide for how to install the driver: [How to install Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-ringtail-nvidia.html)